# What is the range of this mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set, $N = \{a, c, g, t\}$, and $N^3 = N \times N \times N$, now there is a mapping $b: P(N^3) \mapsto N_0, x \mapsto \left\lvert x \right\rvert$. I want to know what is the range of $b$.

When I thought of it, I felt it was $[0, 2^{64})$ as you are mapping a power set of 64 elements to natural numbers.

Can someone please help me figure out if I am right or not? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $N_0$ the set of natural numbers? And is $P$ the power set operator?

Comment: Yes, from 0 to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some questions to get you on the right track: How many elements are there in $N^3$? What is the largest subset of $N^3$ (almost a trick question)? What do you get if you apply $b$ to that set?

Comment: There are 64 elements in $N^3$, and I think $2^{64}$ in the power set of $N^3$. The largest subset would be the set $N^3$ itself right? I felt it gives the cardinalities to the Power set, but a couple of my friends told me, the range is $[0, 64)$ and not $[0,2^{64})$

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj $b$ takes an _element_ of the power set (i.e. a subset of $N^3$) as input, and gives you the cardinality of that set as output. It is largely irrelevant how large the power set itself is.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that, could you please explain how one could come to that conclusion? Is that how mappings work?

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj That's what the notation $P(N^3)\to \Bbb N_0$ means, yes. It signifies a function which to _each element_ of $P(N^3)$ gives an element of $\Bbb N_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much